# How to add event handler to a dynamically created control in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, event-handling

I have searched and seen countless samples here in this forum and in other sites but I'm still stuck with this problem;
I want to add a Click Handler for dynamically created PictureBox-es and pas an argument on it so I know which one of picture boxes was clicked).

Here is my current code:

```
Public Class frmMbarimAbonimi

Private Sub frmMbarimAbonimi_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'FitnessdbDataSet.clients' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    'Me.ClientsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.FitnessdbDataSet.clients)

    '===============
    Dim dt As DataTable = PaPaguar()
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Dim gr(dt.Rows.Count) As GroupBox
    Dim pp(dt.Rows.Count) As PictureBox
    Dim lb(dt.Rows.Count) As Label


    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        gr(i) = New GroupBox
        gr(i).Width = 200
        gr(i).Height = 180

        pp(i) = New PictureBox
        pp(i).SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

        lb(i) = New Label



        '-------------------------
        Try
            Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\Fotot\" + dt.Rows(i).Item("Foto"))
                pp(i).Image = Image.FromStream(str)
            End Using

            lb(i).Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("Emer")

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("Fotoja nuk mund te ngarkohet, ju lutem realizoheni nje foto tjeter!!!")

        End Try
        '-------------------------
        pp(i).Visible = True
        pp(i).Width = 200
        pp(i).Height = 150

        AddHandler pp(i).Click, AddressOf testini



        gr(i).Controls.Add(pp(i))

        lb(i).Visible = True
        lb(i).Width = 200
        lb(i).Height = 30
        lb(i).Left = pp(i).Left
        lb(i).Top = pp(i).Top + 150
        lb(i).BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
        lb(i).BringToFront()
        gr(i).Controls.Add(lb(i))

        flpanel.Controls.Add(gr(i))

        i = i + 1
    Next row
End Sub 
End Class
```

So I was trying to use AddHandler pp(i).Click, AddressOf testini but obviously this does not allow me to call "testini" with a parameter to identify which picture box was clicked.

Can someone point me in the right direction or give some advice? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: You already got the parameter that identifies the picture box, it is the *sender* argument.

Comment: I have been seeing this "sender" thing very often recently but I'm not getting how can I use it in my case. 
'code'
 Public Sub testini(ByVal sender, ByVal EventArgs)

        'How to use it here?

    End Sub

Comment: `sender` is the `PictureBox` that was clicked. In your `testini` method, you could say `Dim pbox As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)` and then do things (change the picture, whatever) with the picture box the user clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add something to your created PictureBox to identify them in the event handler because you can't change the signature of  the click event handler adding a 'parameter'

For example, you could set the Name property

```
pp(i) = New GroupBox
pp(i).Name = "PictureBox" + i.ToString
```

then in the event handler you could recognize your picture box casting the sender object to a picturebox and grabbing the Name property.
Remember, sender is always the control that triggers the event. In your case is always one of your dinamically created PictureBoxes

```
Private Sub testini(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
     Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
     Dim pbIdentity As String = pb.Name
     .....
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the `.Tag` needs to be set on `pp(i)`, not `gr(i)`.

Comment: Rewritten to use the more natural Name property.

Comment: Thanks a Billion Steve, this solved the problem. You're a champion :)